# Is the Carrier Space of a Commutative Banach Algebra Always Nontrivial?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $ A $ be a commutative Banach algebra and let $ \Phi_{A} $ be the carrier space of $ A $, that is, the space consisting of all multiplicative linear functionals from $ A $ to $ \mathbb{C} $.

Certainly the zero functional in always in $ \Phi_A $, but is it ever the case that $ 0 $ is the **only** member of $ \Phi_A $ when $ A $ is commutative?  If so, what are some well known criteria for when $ \Phi_A \neq \{ 0 \} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer, assuming that $A$ is unital and not simply the zero-algebra.

If we assume Zorn's lemma, then there must exist at least one non-zero character.  In particular, it suffices to note that $A$ must have a maximal ideal $I$.  The quotient map $A \mapsto A + I$ is multiplicative, and $A/I \cong \Bbb C$ by the maximality of $I$, the closedness of maximal ideals, and the Gelfand-Mazur theorem.

Comment: What about when $A$ is the zero algebra?  Also, $A/I\cong\mathbb{C}$ follows from maximality but this is nontrivial--it is the Gelfand-Mazur theorem together with the fact that a maximal ideal is closed since all elements sufficiently close to the identity are units.

Comment: It's also not clear whether OP requires their algebras to be unital--given that they consider $0$ to be a multiplicative functional, I would guess that they don't.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the feedback, I put a caveat at the beginning of my answer for now. I agree that $A/I \cong \Bbb C$ deserves more explanation.  I'll add more if I find the time and energy.

Comment: @Eric Regarding your point about non-unital algebras: any algebra without unit can have a unit appended, and if $A$ has dimension greater than $1$ then I believe that every non-zero functional on $A$ comes from a restriction of some non-zero function on the unital extension. In sum: without thinking too carefully, I don't think the fact that the algebras are non-unital should change anything.

Comment: That's not true--for instance, if the multiplication on $A$ is identically $0$, it has no nonzero characters.

Comment: @Eric Woof, I guess I'm rustier with all this than I thought.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten the Gelfand-Mazur theorem.  Thank you for this insight!